# What should I use spin lock or mutex if conflict doesn't occur often

Tags: .net, mutex, spinlock

I'm fixing one bug related to concurrent access to collections in one library. Currently library uses Mutex(lock) to control access from multiple threads. Locked areas in code contains code that should be executed quite fast (modifying list/dictionary or read from it) so spin lock seems to match this scenario.

But ...
In most cases lock is not necessary because majority of apps that uses this library are single-threaded and it is important for me to do not slow them down.
Mine naive benchmark indicates that spin lock checks slower that resource is not used, but I do not fully trust it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are advertising this function as *thread safe* then you should provide locking on collection updates.

If not, make sure you document the fact and leave it up to the consumer.

Comment: The question is if spin lock doesn't affect performance more than regular lock. Functions should be thread safe because some customers (especially me) uses it in multi-threaded environment.